# Python: How to check that every character in a list is not ' '?

Tags: python

I'm building a simple tic tac toe game in `Python`.

I have a list which has 10 spaces in it that I replace each go with an `X` or an `O`. I want it to be able to tell when the board is full, and there was no winner. I have all the winning possibilities laid out already, and this was my attempt at trying to get it to check for a draw.

`for char in begin_board[1:10]:
     if char != ' ':
         print("It's a draw!")`

This is wrong as it's only checking if `1` of the `9` isn't a space. I want it to check and only return the print if all `9` are not spaces.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you're looking for `if not ' ' in begin_board: ...`

Comment: You have a few options.  You could simply count the number of moves and realize the board is full after certain number of moves have been made. Or you could use `all()`.  `if all(c != ' ' for c in begin_board[1:10]):`.  Or most simply `if ' ' not in begin_board[1:10]:`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the negative by checking the empty string is `not in` your list.

```
if ' ' not in board:
     # Board is full.
```

If you use `''` for your empty square value you can also use `all()` to check that all values are `True`. An empty string already has a `False` value in Python, and any other string is `True` so you can just test the board directly.

```
>>> board = ['x', 'x', '']
>>> all(board)
False

>>> board = ['x', 'x', 'o']
>>> all(board)
```

You would use it as

```
if all(board):
    # Board is full.
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, `begin_board[1:10]` will list down 2nd to 9th only. If that's the behaviour that you're going for then this is fine otherwise, If you want all elements then just do for i in begin_board and it will list down all elements from first to tenth

If we are to go with your own code then this can be done like this by using a isDraw flag and checking if there are any empty spaces left.

```
for i in begin_board:
    if char==' ':
        isDraw = False
if (isDraw):
    print("It's a draw!")
```

a better way to achieve this however can be counting how many spaces are present in the list.

```
if (begin_board.count(' ') == 0):
    print("It's a draw")
```

another way is to check whether spaces exist in the board at all or not simply by.

```
if ' ' not in begin_board:
    print("It's a draw")
```